# A Monster Puzzle

Tags: word

Each clue has an associated word, use the associated words to give you the final answer.

Clue #1: Digital, Country, South

Clue #2: Monkey, Red, Serial

Clue #3: Traffic, In, Con

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Clue #1 (credit to Matt)

> **Western**
>  Western Digital, Country/Western music, South Western Airlines

Clue #2 (credit to Techidiot)

> **Code**
>  Code Monkey, Code Red, Serial Code

Clue #3 (credit to Matt again)

> **Junction**
>  Traffic Junction, injunction, conjunction

Final Answer

> **Spaghetti**
>  [Spaghetti Western](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_Western), [Spaghetti Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), [Spaghetti Junction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_Junction)

Comment: Completely right, good work!

Answer (score 7):

**Partial Answer**

1

> Western
>  Western Digital is a hard drive company, Country/Western music, and South Western is an airline as well as a direction.

3

> Junction
>  Traffic Junction, injunction, and conjunction.

Answer (score 7):

Clue #2: Monkey, Red, Serial

> [Code Monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_monkey)
>  [Code Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_Red)
>  [Serial Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_code)
>
>  Hence the word is $\rightarrow$ **CODE**